# Winforms, How to separate tab index on user controls in the same form?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabindex

I have a winform to which I add a table layout panel with 2 rows and 2 columns.
To each cell I add a different user control with its own tab index order,
The problem is that it seems that the tab index is joind to all the form, meaning:

```
UserControl1 has 4 textboxes with tab index: 0,1,2,3
UserControl2 has 4 textboxes with tab index: 0,1,2,3
UserControl3 has 4 textboxes with tab index: 0,1,2,3
UserControl4 has 4 textboxes with tab index: 0,1,2,3
```

When I'm in UserContrl1 textbox1 and pressing tab it goes to UserControl2 textbox1 instead
of going to UserControl1 textbox2.
All the controls are loaded dynamically so the tab index is computed in a loop.
Is there a way to tell the form to treat the tab key only on the user control order and not the form ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the helper of visual studio. 
In the menu view you have tab order like that you can define the order of tabs.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Not if he is generating the controls during runtime ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you generate the usercontrols anyway, what keeps you from setting the tab index like this?

```
UserControl1 has 4 textboxes with tab index: 0,1,2,3
UserControl2 has 4 textboxes with tab index: 4,5,6,7
UserControl3 has 4 textboxes with tab index: 8,9,10,11
UserControl4 has 4 textboxes with tab index: 12,13,14,15
```

Another guess would be only to set the TabIndex of the usercontrols itself:

```
UserControl1.TabIndex = 0; 4 textboxes with tab index: 0,1,2,3
UserControl2.TabIndex = 1; 4 textboxes with tab index: 0,1,2,3
UserControl3.TabIndex = 2; 4 textboxes with tab index: 0,1,2,3
UserControl4.TabIndex = 3; 4 textboxes with tab index: 0,1,2,3
```

Comment: It's a loop that runs from start each time